# Converting ts to mp4 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video

I've tried what feels like a million ffmpeg wrappers and none of them seem to work, so I thought I'd ask here. How would one go about losslessly converting .ts files to .mp4 with Python? Every ffmpeg wrapper I've tried has not worked despite both the ffmpeg bin and .exe being in the PATH and every installation step followed. Is there a simple wrapper that I can use? I hate to ask for a step-by-step, but I must be doing something wrong, right?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what hasn't worked for you so far and how it didn't work?

Comment: @Ownaginatious ffmpy, python-video-converter, and one or two others. mhawke has already posted a solution, though, so hopefully I won't need to use those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your conversion requirements are specific, why don't you just call `ffmpeg` directly from Python with [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (Python >= 3.5) or [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) (Python < 3.5)?

```
import subprocess

infile = 'video.ts'
outfile = 'video.mp4'

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', infile, outfile])
```

You can capture the output if wanted. Refer to the documentation for that.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @displayname: glad it helped.