# Iterate flv files in a folder and convert them to mp4 format

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

If I have a folder which has many flv format files, and I want to iterate these flv files and convert them to mp4 format using `Python` and `ffmpeg`. I would like to keep the files' original names except replacing their extension `.flv` with `.mp4`.

I tried iterate flv files, and convert one flv file to mp4 format, but I don't know how to convert all flv files in Python. Thanks for your help at advance.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

# Iterate all flv files in a folder
for file in glob.glob('*.flv'):
    print(file)

# Convert one flv file to mp4 file
inputfile = 'video.flv'
outputfile = 'video.mp4'

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', inputfile, outputfile])
```

Reference:
[Converting ts to mp4 with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105973/converting-ts-to-mp4-with-python)

Comment: "Here is what I have tried:" - okay, cool, what's your question?

Comment: subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i file video.mp4') this line obviously will not iterate and and convert all the flv files. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works. Thanks to my colleague!

```
import subprocess
import os

src = r'D:\files'
dst = r'D:\files\mp4'

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src, topdown=False):
    #print(filenames)
    for filename in filenames:
        if ".flv" in filename:
            inputfile = os.path.join(root, filename)
            #print(inputfile)
            outputfile = os.path.join(dst, filename.replace(".flv", ".mp4"))
            subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', inputfile, outputfile])
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. At the top

```
import os
```

Inside your loop:

```
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i {0}.flv {0}.mp4'.format(name))
```